# Amplitude decrease during geometrical spreading of a seismic pulse

Tags: energy, geophysics

I'm looking at amplitude decrease of a seismic pulse as a result of geometrical spreading.

Starting with the energy contained in a unit area, $I = E / (4 \pi r^2)$, where $E$ is the original energy from source, we know that energy falls off as $1/r^2$, thus amplitude falls off as $1/r$.

From Wikipedia:

> "The energy or intensity decreases (divided by $4$) as the distance $r$ is doubled"

This makes sense to me, as when $r$ is doubled we have the energy divided by $(2r)^2 = 4r^2$ (which is $4  \times r^2$).

From this same principle, I would expect that the amplitude is divided by 2 when the distance is doubled as we have $1/2r$ instead of $1/r$.

However from a Louisiana State University website:

> Geomteric spreading makes the amplitude of a signal falls off in proportion to the distance traveled by the ray. So that if the path of flight is doubled the amplitude will decrease by a factor of ${\sqrt 2}$.

I can't see how they got their factor of $√2$ instead of $2$.

Is there a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but could the article be referring to [Rayleigh waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_wave) or [Love waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_waves)? These are surface waves, so the energy is spread out over the circumference of a circle not the surface of a sphere. This produces a $1/r$ dependance of the energy and therefore a $1/\sqrt{r}$ dependence of the amplitude.

**Response to comment:**

The bit of the article you reference says:

> Geomteric (sic) spreading makes the amplitude of a signal falls off in proportion to the distance traveled by the ray.

then

> So that if the path of flight is doubled the amplitude will decrease by a factor of: square root of 2.

Assuming the first sentence actually means *the amplitude of a signal falls off in **inverse** proportion* these two aren't consistent. The second sentence must be a typo - probably a copy and paste error.

Comment: Article seems to suggest body waves:

http://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/ReflectSeismol13/lectures/html/Maintext.html

subheading is "(1) Geometric Spreading (Spherical divergence)"

Comment: That has to be a typo

Comment: Yah I figured it meant inverse proportion. There are quite a few typos so it's quite possible. I'll go with that. cheers.